# how to select all children elements and their attributes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When the document loads I want to get the attribute href of each button under the class playlist.

my HTML code

```
    <div class="playlist p-5">

  <div class="song p-3">
    <span><button href="song.mp3" class="songlink btn"> song 1<i class="fa fa-play playbtn"></i></button></span>
    <div class="wavetest"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="song p-3">
    <span><button href="song2.m4a" class="songlink btn"> song 2<i class="fa fa-play playbtn"></i></button></span>
    <div class="wavetest"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="song p-3">
    <span><button href="song3.mp3" class="songlink btn"> song 3<i class="fa fa-play playbtn"></i></button></span>
    <div class="wavetest"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

my jquery code gives me only href of the first button.
here is my jQuery code.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  alert($('.playlist').find('button').attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: Without jquery: `Array.from($('.playlist').querySelectorAll('button')).map(x => x.getAttribute('href'))`

Comment: Start with `$('.playlist button').each(function(i) { let thisHref = $(this).attr('href'); })`

Comment: @freedomn-m: there almost always is! ;)

Comment: To apply the existing question here: `var hrefs = $('.playlist button').map((i, e) => $(e).attr("href")).get();`

Comment: But you did use jQuery @enno.void...

Comment: Note that there are 3 types (probably others...) of return from jquery functions:  a jquery collection eg `$("button")`, a boolean eg `$(".class").is(".class")` and a value `.attr("href")`  - the "value" will depend on the method being called - so *always* check the documentation.     eg .text() will *combine all* the elements into a string single while  .attr will return the attr only for the *first* entry.

Comment: @Shai no $() is a shortcut available in all modern browsers

Comment: @enno.void only in the console?   Gives `$ is not defined` https://jsfiddle.net/jx68zgrp/

Comment: @freedomn-m yes, outside of devtools you have to use the real function or define the alias by urself: "When called with one argument, this function is an alias for the document.querySelector() function." - From the docs https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/